# What happens if I use a DC adapter with a15v output with a PC monitor with a 14v rating?

Tags: voltage, dc, adapter, monitor

I have a PC monitor with a 14v rating but it's original DC adapter  is broken. Can I safely use a similar DC adapter from a similar monitor, but with 15v output instead? How likely is the 14v monitor to suffer a burnout?

Comment: This heavily depends on the technology inside the monitor and the adapter. Can you provide more detail? Have you actually measured the 15v?(some adapter technologies lead to considerably higher free-wheeling voltages) are both adapters the same level of security (look for the logo for protected/grounded)?

Answer (score 2):

The power adapter probably feeds into a number of voltage regulators or DC to DC voltage converters so the circuits will get the proper voltages ahead of the adapter.  Equipment is designed so that it can handle a certain range of voltages to allow for voltage drift caused by aging components and/or other problems caused by open capacitors etc. I have never needed to change an adapter for a monitor but have replaced adapters that were not exactly the same voltage as the original for laptops and other equipment and have had no problems.  If this were my equpment, I would try the adapter provided it was the same polarity.  Reverse polarity will definitely damage the equipment but one volt higher probably won't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Proceed at your own risk. It's impossible to say without knowing the circuitry of the PC monitor, but, more than likely the 7% overvoltage will be fine and you won't notice any difference.

But again, no guarantees.